# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/types/GenericArrayData

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib

When I run this code

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("MLlib")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)  

val data = sc.textFile("hdfs://192.168.1.20:8020/user/sparkMLlib/input/testMLlib.csv")
val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(',').map(_.toDouble))).cache()

// Cluster the data into two classes using KMeans
val numClusters = 2
val numIterations = 20
val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)

// Evaluate clustering by computing Within Set Sum of Squared Errors
val WSSSE = clusters.computeCost(parsedData)
println("Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = " + WSSSE)
// Save and load model
clusters.save(sc, "hdfs://192.168.1.20:8020/user/sparkMLlib/output/")
val sameModel = KMeansModel.load(sc, "hdfs://192.168.1.20:8020/user/sparkMLlib/output/")
```

I get a runtime exception:

```
16/05/04 14:43:40 ERROR DefaultWriterContainer: Aborting task.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/types/GenericArrayData
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT.serialize(Vectors.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT.serialize(Vectors.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$UDTConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$productToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$productToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.GenericArrayData
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I don't understand this at all.Is it a import or dependency problem ,I looked everywhere but I find nothing.It seems a really strange exception to get. Can anyone explain?

Comment: can you show your dependencies (pom / sbt / gradle..)? looks like you're missing a dependency on `org.apache.spark:spark-sql`

Comment: yes it's problem with version of spark-sql. Thank you fo your help